# Анимация стрелки svg в зависимости от положения курсора мыши

Tags: javascript, svg, анимация, svg-animation

Есть анимированная `svg` стрелка в двух положениях, работает при наведении на основе [топика в смежной теме](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60955939/7394871), но не совсем понимаю как сделать так, чтобы стрелка при наведении мыши переходила в конечное положение и фиксировалась, а при отведении мыши возвращалась в начальное состояние?

```js
document.querySelector("svg").addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  this.getElementsByTagName("animate")[0].beginElement();
});
```

```css
svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 80 80" version="1.1" fill="none"><path id="path" d="M53.0607 41.0607C53.6464 40.4749 53.6464 39.5251 53.0607 38.9393L43.5147 29.3934C42.9289 28.8076 41.9792 28.8076 41.3934 29.3934C40.8076 29.9792 40.8076 30.9289 41.3934 31.5147L49.8787 40L41.3934 48.4853C40.8076 49.0711 40.8076 50.0208 41.3934 50.6066C41.9792 51.1924 42.9289 51.1924 43.5147 50.6066L53.0607 41.0607ZM27 41.5H52V38.5H27V41.5Z" fill="black"><animate id="_animate" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" values="M53.0607 41.0607C53.6464 40.4749 53.6464 39.5251 53.0607 38.9393L43.5147 29.3934C42.9289 28.8076 41.9792 28.8076 41.3934 29.3934C40.8076 29.9792 40.8076 30.9289 41.3934 31.5147L49.8787 40L41.3934 48.4853C40.8076 49.0711 40.8076 50.0208 41.3934 50.6066C41.9792 51.1924 42.9289 51.1924 43.5147 50.6066L53.0607 41.0607ZM27 41.5H52V38.5H27V41.5Z; M64.0607 41.0607C64.6464 40.4749 64.6464 39.5251 64.0607 38.9393L54.5147 29.3934C53.9289 28.8076 52.9792 28.8076 52.3934 29.3934C51.8076 29.9792 51.8076 30.9289 52.3934 31.5147L60.8787 40L52.3934 48.4853C51.8076 49.0711 51.8076 50.0208 52.3934 50.6066C52.9792 51.1924 53.9289 51.1924 54.5147 50.6066L64.0607 41.0607ZM18 41.5H63V38.5H18V41.5Z; M53.0607 41.0607C53.6464 40.4749 53.6464 39.5251 53.0607 38.9393L43.5147 29.3934C42.9289 28.8076 41.9792 28.8076 41.3934 29.3934C40.8076 29.9792 40.8076 30.9289 41.3934 31.5147L49.8787 40L41.3934 48.4853C40.8076 49.0711 40.8076 50.0208 41.3934 50.6066C41.9792 51.1924 42.9289 51.1924 43.5147 50.6066L53.0607 41.0607ZM27 41.5H52V38.5H27V41.5Z" fill="freeze" /></path><rect x="1" y="1" width="78" height="78" rx="39" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я немного переформатирую ваш код, чтобы внести ясность:

```js
document.querySelector("svg").addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  this.getElementsByTagName("animate")[0].beginElement();
});
```

```html
<style>
svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 80 80" version="1.1" fill="none">
  <path id="path" d="M53.0607 41.0607C53.6464 40.4749 53.6464 39.5251 53.0607 38.9393L43.5147 29.3934C42.9289 28.8076 41.9792 28.8076 41.3934 29.3934C40.8076 29.9792 40.8076 30.9289 41.3934 31.5147L49.8787 40L41.3934 48.4853C40.8076 49.0711 40.8076 50.0208 41.3934 50.6066C41.9792 51.1924 42.9289 51.1924 43.5147 50.6066L53.0607 41.0607ZM27 41.5H52V38.5H27V41.5Z" fill="black">
 <animate id="_animate" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" values="
    M53.0607 41.0607C53.6464 40.4749 53.6464 39.5251 53.0607 38.9393L43.5147 29.3934C42.9289 28.8076 41.9792 28.8076 41.3934 29.3934C40.8076 29.9792 40.8076 30.9289 41.3934 31.5147L49.8787 40L41.3934 48.4853C40.8076 49.0711 40.8076 50.0208 41.3934 50.6066C41.9792 51.1924 42.9289 51.1924 43.5147 50.6066L53.0607 41.0607ZM27 41.5H52V38.5H27V41.5Z;
    M64.0607 41.0607C64.6464 40.4749 64.6464 39.5251 64.0607 38.9393L54.5147 29.3934C53.9289 28.8076 52.9792 28.8076 52.3934 29.3934C51.8076 29.9792 51.8076 30.9289 52.3934 31.5147L60.8787 40L52.3934 48.4853C51.8076 49.0711 51.8076 50.0208 52.3934 50.6066C52.9792 51.1924 53.9289 51.1924 54.5147 50.6066L64.0607 41.0607ZM18 41.5H63V38.5H18V41.5Z;
    M53.0607 41.0607C53.6464 40.4749 53.6464 39.5251 53.0607 38.9393L43.5147 29.3934C42.9289 28.8076 41.9792 28.8076 41.3934 29.3934C40.8076 29.9792 40.8076 30.9289 41.3934 31.5147L49.8787 40L41.3934 48.4853C40.8076 49.0711 40.8076 50.0208 41.3934 50.6066C41.9792 51.1924 42.9289 51.1924 43.5147 50.6066L53.0607 41.0607ZM27 41.5H52V38.5H27V41.5Z" fill="freeze" />
    </path>
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="78" height="78" rx="39" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

***Анимация размера стрелки в вашем коде:***

**M53... ;** Начальный размер стрелки
**M64... ;** конечный, увеличенный размер стрелки
**M53... ;** Возврат к начальному  размеру стрелки

Это замкнутый цикл роста и уменьшения стрелки, поэтому
эту анимацию нужно разбить на две анимации:
*1. Анимация роста стрелки при наведении*

**M53... ;** Начальный размер стрелки
**M64... ;** конечный, увеличенный размер стрелки

```
document.querySelector("svg").addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  this.getElementsByTagName("animate")[0].beginElement(); 
   });
```

*2. Анимация уменьшения стрелки при отводе курсора:*

**M64... ;** конечный, увеличенный размер стрелки
**M53... ;** Возврат к начальному  размеру стрелки

```
document.querySelector("svg").addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  this.getElementsByTagName("animate")[1].beginElement();
 });
```

Ниже полный код, который реализует рост стрелки при наведении и уменьшения её при отводе курсора:

```js
document.querySelector("svg").addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  this.getElementsByTagName("animate")[0].beginElement(); 
  
 }); 
document.querySelector("svg").addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  this.getElementsByTagName("animate")[1].beginElement();
 });
```

```css
svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 80 80" version="1.1" fill="none">
  <path id="path" d="M53.0607 41.0607C53.6464 40.4749 53.6464 39.5251 53.0607 38.9393L43.5147 29.3934C42.9289 28.8076 41.9792 28.8076 41.3934 29.3934C40.8076 29.9792 40.8076 30.9289 41.3934 31.5147L49.8787 40L41.3934 48.4853C40.8076 49.0711 40.8076 50.0208 41.3934 50.6066C41.9792 51.1924 42.9289 51.1924 43.5147 50.6066L53.0607 41.0607ZM27 41.5H52V38.5H27V41.5Z" fill="black">
 <!-- Увеличение стрелки при наведении курсора -->
 <animate id="_animate" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur=".5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"
 values="
      M53.0607 41.0607C53.6464 40.4749 53.6464 39.5251 53.0607 38.9393L43.5147 29.3934C42.9289 28.8076 41.9792 28.8076 41.3934 29.3934C40.8076 29.9792 40.8076 30.9289 41.3934 31.5147L49.8787 40L41.3934 48.4853C40.8076 49.0711 40.8076 50.0208 41.3934 50.6066C41.9792 51.1924 42.9289 51.1924 43.5147 50.6066L53.0607 41.0607ZM27 41.5H52V38.5H27V41.5Z;    
      M64.0607 41.0607C64.6464 40.4749 64.6464 39.5251 64.0607 38.9393L54.5147 29.3934C53.9289 28.8076 52.9792 28.8076 52.3934 29.3934C51.8076 29.9792 51.8076 30.9289 52.3934 31.5147L60.8787 40L52.3934 48.4853C51.8076 49.0711 51.8076 50.0208 52.3934 50.6066C52.9792 51.1924 53.9289 51.1924 54.5147 50.6066L64.0607 41.0607ZM18 41.5H63V38.5H18V41.5Z" /> 
<!-- Уменьшение стрелки при отводе курсора --> 
 <animate id="_animate2" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur=".5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" 
      values="
        M64.0607 41.0607C64.6464 40.4749 64.6464 39.5251 64.0607 38.9393L54.5147 29.3934C53.9289 28.8076 52.9792 28.8076 52.3934 29.3934C51.8076 29.9792 51.8076 30.9289 52.3934 31.5147L60.8787 40L52.3934 48.4853C51.8076 49.0711 51.8076 50.0208 52.3934 50.6066C52.9792 51.1924 53.9289 51.1924 54.5147 50.6066L64.0607 41.0607ZM18 41.5H63V38.5H18V41.5Z;
        M53.0607 41.0607C53.6464 40.4749 53.6464 39.5251 53.0607 38.9393L43.5147 29.3934C42.9289 28.8076 41.9792 28.8076 41.3934 29.3934C40.8076 29.9792 40.8076 30.9289 41.3934 31.5147L49.8787 40L41.3934 48.4853C40.8076 49.0711 40.8076 50.0208 41.3934 50.6066C41.9792 51.1924 42.9289 51.1924 43.5147 50.6066L53.0607 41.0607ZM27 41.5H52V38.5H27V41.5Z" />
    </path>
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="78" height="78" rx="39" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: супер, спасибо большое! Для вот это `("animate")[0]` и `("animate")[1]` было не очевидно

Comment: @Вася Скорее было не очевидно, что одну анимацию изменения пути туда-сюда для стрелки, нужно было разбить на две отдельные анимации роста и уменьшения стрелки. А решить это можно было чисто командами smil без JS

Comment: @Вася Добавил пример без JS

Answer (score 2):

### Решение pure smil svg (без JS)

Всё точно также, как в примере с JS, но условием запуска анимации роста стрелки является команда smil - `begin="svg1.mouseover"`

Команда анимации уменьшения стрелки `begin="svg1.mouseleave"`, где svg1 это ID SVG блока.

```html
<style>
svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 80 80" version="1.1" fill="none">
  <path id="path" d="M53.0607 41.0607C53.6464 40.4749 53.6464 39.5251 53.0607 38.9393L43.5147 29.3934C42.9289 28.8076 41.9792 28.8076 41.3934 29.3934C40.8076 29.9792 40.8076 30.9289 41.3934 31.5147L49.8787 40L41.3934 48.4853C40.8076 49.0711 40.8076 50.0208 41.3934 50.6066C41.9792 51.1924 42.9289 51.1924 43.5147 50.6066L53.0607 41.0607ZM27 41.5H52V38.5H27V41.5Z" fill="black">
 <animate id="_animate" attributeName="d" begin="svg1.mouseover" dur=".5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"
 values="
      M53.0607 41.0607C53.6464 40.4749 53.6464 39.5251 53.0607 38.9393L43.5147 29.3934C42.9289 28.8076 41.9792 28.8076 41.3934 29.3934C40.8076 29.9792 40.8076 30.9289 41.3934 31.5147L49.8787 40L41.3934 48.4853C40.8076 49.0711 40.8076 50.0208 41.3934 50.6066C41.9792 51.1924 42.9289 51.1924 43.5147 50.6066L53.0607 41.0607ZM27 41.5H52V38.5H27V41.5Z;    
      M64.0607 41.0607C64.6464 40.4749 64.6464 39.5251 64.0607 38.9393L54.5147 29.3934C53.9289 28.8076 52.9792 28.8076 52.3934 29.3934C51.8076 29.9792 51.8076 30.9289 52.3934 31.5147L60.8787 40L52.3934 48.4853C51.8076 49.0711 51.8076 50.0208 52.3934 50.6066C52.9792 51.1924 53.9289 51.1924 54.5147 50.6066L64.0607 41.0607ZM18 41.5H63V38.5H18V41.5Z" /> 
 
 <animate id="_animate2" attributeName="d" begin="svg1.mouseleave" dur=".5s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" 
      values="
        M64.0607 41.0607C64.6464 40.4749 64.6464 39.5251 64.0607 38.9393L54.5147 29.3934C53.9289 28.8076 52.9792 28.8076 52.3934 29.3934C51.8076 29.9792 51.8076 30.9289 52.3934 31.5147L60.8787 40L52.3934 48.4853C51.8076 49.0711 51.8076 50.0208 52.3934 50.6066C52.9792 51.1924 53.9289 51.1924 54.5147 50.6066L64.0607 41.0607ZM18 41.5H63V38.5H18V41.5Z;
        M53.0607 41.0607C53.6464 40.4749 53.6464 39.5251 53.0607 38.9393L43.5147 29.3934C42.9289 28.8076 41.9792 28.8076 41.3934 29.3934C40.8076 29.9792 40.8076 30.9289 41.3934 31.5147L49.8787 40L41.3934 48.4853C40.8076 49.0711 40.8076 50.0208 41.3934 50.6066C41.9792 51.1924 42.9289 51.1924 43.5147 50.6066L53.0607 41.0607ZM27 41.5H52V38.5H27V41.5Z" />
</path>
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="78" height="78" rx="39" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```